# mysql table fields - Resource id #7

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table in the database:

```
id, username, email, old_ip, current_ip
```

Everytime the user logs in, I want their current ip to be stored in current_ip. But before that I want to save their old_ip (from last login) so I thought I could move what is in current_ip to old_ip before copying the new data to current_ip.

I wrote this script when logging in:

```
........
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password'"); 
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($login_check > 0){ 
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
    // Get member ID into a session variable
    $id = $row["id"];   
    session_register('id'); 
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    // Get member username into a session variable
    $username = $row["username"];   
    session_register('username'); 
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;


    // IP getting
    $old_ip = mysql_query("SELECT current_ip FROM members WHERE id='$id'");
    $result_old_ip = $old_ip;
    $sql_setoldip = mysql_query("UPDATE members SET old_ip='".$result_old_ip."' WHERE id='$id'");


    $getip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    $current_ip = $getip;
    // Update ip in database
    mysql_query("UPDATE members SET current_ip='".$current_ip."' WHERE id='$id'");

}
```

The result I get in the old_ip feild is "Resource id #7" Any help please ?

Comment: You are running a SELECT query with the correct syntax just ten lines upwards...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mysql_query()` statement returns a resource pointer to the result set, not the data itself. You'll need to use `mysql_fetch_array()` in order to retrieve the actual data in the table.

like this:

```
$old_ip = mysql_query("SELECT current_ip FROM members WHERE id='$id'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($old_ip);
$result_old_ip = $row['current_ip'];
```

this will solve your problem.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to [fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) the result from your `select` first.

You can by the way do this in one query:

`UPDATE members SET old_ip = current_ip, current_ip = '$newip' WHERE id= $id`

And don't use [`session_register`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-register.php), it's deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Correction:

```
...
// IP getting
$old_ip = mysql_query("SELECT current_ip FROM members WHERE id='$id'");
list($result_old_ip) = mysql_fetch_row($old_ip);
...
```

However, this has no error checking, also the rest of the code, so please read after, how to protect agains SQL injection and insert some error checking.

Comment: Cheers, yes I should consider security a bit more. I am planning to spend more time on this thank you